# meta_search wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using meta_search plugin with my rails3 app for search functionality. When I want to try the search method of meta_search plugin on my model in console, it gives me this error. I am not able to figure the error from the plugin source code.

```
Listing.search(:address1_starts_with => ["lucky"])
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

please help

Comment: Can you put the complete stacktrace please ?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to this party but you shouldn't be supplying the parameter as an array.

```
Listing.search(:address1_starts_with => "lucky")
```

should do the trick.